# Como saber se uma variável já foi definida no Bash?

Tags: bash

Tenho uma aplicação que roda a partir de um script `sh`. Eu tenho nesse script definido algumas variáveis, onde eu uso `export` para ser acessado internamente pela aplicação.

Porém, agora tenho a necessidade de só definir essa variável caso a mesma não exista. Eu não me dou muito bem com o bash, então gostaria de saber:

Existe alguma maneira de verificar se uma variável foi definida no BASH?

```bsh
# Se a variável API_BASE_URL não foi definida, cria...
export API_BASE_URL="http://localhost"
```

Comment: Tenta: if [ -z "$var" ]; then echo "var is blank"; else echo "var is set to '$var'"; fi, em que "var" você substitui por sua variável

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um jeito de fazer é:

```
export API_BASE_URL=${API_BASE_URL:="http://localhost"}
```

Se a variável já existe, usa o valor atual. Caso contrário, usa `http://localhost`. Só que o valor também é setado caso a variável seja uma string vazia. Ou seja:

```bsh
export API_BASE_URL="a"
export API_BASE_URL=${API_BASE_URL:="http://localhost"}
echo $API_BASE_URL # imprime "a"
```

```bsh
export API_BASE_URL=""
export API_BASE_URL=${API_BASE_URL:="http://localhost"}
echo $API_BASE_URL # imprime "http://localhost"
```

```bsh
export API_BASE_URL=${API_BASE_URL:="http://localhost"}
echo $API_BASE_URL # imprime "http://localhost"
```

---

Outra opção é usar `-z`:

```
[ -z "$API_BASE_URL" ] && export API_BASE_URL="http://localhost"
```

Com o mesmo comportamento da primeira opção (se a variável não existir ou for string vazia, atribui-se o novo valor).

---

Mas se você não quer setar o valor caso a variável já exista e seja a string vazia, mude para:

```
export API_BASE_URL=${API_BASE_URL="http://localhost"}
```